# Perl grep a range on values in an array

Tags: regex, perl, grep

Contents of file:

```
Number of items Enabled:43
Number of items Enabled:95
```

Command to grep out any value within the file between 41-59

```
grep -E '5[1-9]|4[1-9]$' test.txt
```

Returns

```
Number of items Enabled:43
```

I need to do the same thing within an array which has the same contents. Currently i'm using the below command to return a specific number but want to look up the same range 41-59:

```
if (grep(/43/,  @TESTARRAY)) {}
```

I can't seem to get the syntax correct

Comment: I think you had to use `grep -E '(5[1-9]|4[1-9])$' test.txt` before so that `$` pertained to both the branches.

Answer (score 1):

That's because regular expressions are about *patterns* not _values. `grep` simply doesn't understand relative value.

You need to extract the value first:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;


while (<DATA>) {
   if (   m/Enabled:(\d+)/
      and $1 > 41
      and $1 < 59 )
   {
      print;
   }
}

__DATA__
Number of items Enabled:43
Number of items Enabled:95
```

The `grep` function can be used in a similar way:

```
print grep { m/Enabled:(\d+)/ and $1 > 41 and $1 < 59 } <DATA>;
```

You shouldn't try and construct a regex for selecting a numeric range - it'll lead you into madness.

Comment: *"You shouldn't try and construct a regex for selecting a numeric range - it'll lead you into madness"* [Number::Range::Regex](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Range::Regex) may preserve your sanity

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

    while(<DATA>){
        if ( m/.*?Enabled:(4[1-9])|(5[0-9])/){
            print $_;
        }
    }

__DATA__
Number of items Enabled:43
Number of items Enabled:50
Number of items Enabled:52
Number of items Enabled:40

m/.*?Enabled:(4[1-9])|(5[0-9])/
```

1)`.*?` is a non-greedy regex, this means that it will match anything until the next element
 from your regex is found ( in this case : "Enabled")

2) `Enabled:` matches the string `Enabled:`

3)`(4[1-9])|5[0-9])`
    3.1) `(4[1-9])` will search for a 4 followed by a number between 1-9
`|`or
3.2)`(5[0-9])` will search for a 5 followed by a number between 0-9

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really different, note that you can avoid the alternation for this specific case:

```
print join " ", grep(/\b([45][0-9])$/ && $1 != 40, qw(12 18 41 52 40 59 64))
```